# pyautogui.click() moves to destination but doesn't click

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the code i have

```
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
def click(x1,y1):
    pyautogui.click(x=x1,y=y1)
    time.sleep(0.01)
    

while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:

    if pyautogui.pixel(750, 400)[0] == 0:
        click(750, 400)
    if pyautogui.pixel(890, 400)[0] == 0:
        click(890, 400)
    if pyautogui.pixel(1020, 400)[0] == 0:
        click(1020, 400)
    if pyautogui.pixel(1164, 400)[0] == 0:
        click(1164, 400)
```

i ran it with console and administrator and it still doesn't click
also tried with pyautogui.mouseDown()\mouseUp() but it still didn't

Edit: The problem was with the site not the code

Answer (score 0):

try moving the pointer first using

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x , y)
```

then click using

```
pyautogui.click()
```

Comment: it moves to the position just fine the problem is that it doesn't click on it
edit: just tested it didn't work. but when an ad played over the game then it clicked... so it might be that the game has anti-bot protection? (https://www.gamesgames.com/game/magic-piano-tiles)